# Azure speech services speech to text error

Tags: c#, azure, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, speech

I have a free trial account of Azure speech services and I use speech to text services in a program using c#.

The utility of the program is to conevrt file audios to text files, by speech to text API. The problem is taht sometimes an error appears saying:

> Status: Canceled. Reason: The recognition service encountered an internal error and could not continue.Respones
>   text:{"Duration":0,"Offset":0,"RecognitionStatus":"Error"}.

Someone can help me if I have an error in the program or there is a problem of the free account in azure that gives problems?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I found that the type a WAV file I used gave me that error, I converted it be mono using FFMPEG in Docker using the following command line in PowerShell.

```
mkdir $pwd\original\output\ -Force 
docker run -v ${PWD}\original:/tmp/workdir jrottenberg/ffmpeg  -i Dummycall.wav -map_channel 0.0.0 DummycallMono.wav
```

Please be aware that you may need to run this for left and right channels by modifying the arguments using -map_channel 0.0.1